# HTML change line break trigger?

Tags: html, css, web

Is there any way in CSS/HTML to change what characters cause linebreaks in text to be allowed? For example if I have table data containing the text "fooooooo/barrrrrrrrr" it won't get split on two lines, but if it contains "fooooooo barrrrrrrrr" it will.

Is there a way to add punctuation characters to what can trigger line break?

Comment: You mean word wrap, not line break. Those are two different things.

Comment: Is `<br>` too many characters?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It is not possible in CSS/HTML to change the set of characters that cause, allow, or prevent linebreaks in text. However, it is possible to affect such things per each *occurrence* of a character. That is, you cannot say in general “linebreak after ‘/’ is allowed”, but you can inject some markup or content after a particular occurrence of “/” to allow a line break there.

Note that browsers have different line breaking behavior. For example, Opera treats the slash “/” as allowing a line break after it. The behavior may also depend on the context. See my page on [line breaking in browsers](http://www.cs.tut.fi/~jkorpela/html/nobr.html).

Thinks used to be simple, to anyone who knew the practical method and wasn’t too worried about the reluctance of standardizers to accept it: the `<wbr>` tag. It is still the simple practical way, e.g. `fooooooo/<wbr>barrrrrrrrr`, but it isn’t the most cross-browser way any more. The newer way, the zero-width space U+200B, which can be written as `&#x200b;` in HTML, works well on modern browsers, but on some old versions of IE, it creates a mess (a small rectangle is displayed where this control character appears).

If you are willing to use somewhat verbose code, you can combine the two ways. You would use both `<wbr>` and an inline element with empty content but with zero-width space as generated content. This avoids the problem on IE 6, as it does not support generated content in CSS (but recognizes the `<wbr>` markup). Example:

```
fooooooo/<wbr><a class=wbr></a>barrrrrrrrr
```

with CSS code

```
.wbr:after { content: "\00200B"; }
```

Test and demo: [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/yxRUQ/).

Answer (score 5):

You could use [css word-wrap property](http://www.w3schools.com/css3/css3_text_effects.asp#normal) so your long word gets broken according to its container width:

```
word-wrap: break-word;
```

Comment: This is by far the simplest way to make this happen.

Answer (score 4):

No, but there are Unicode characters (most notably, U+200B ZERO WIDTH SPACE) which will allow a line break at a specified point while not inserting any visible characters or space.

Answer (score 1):

There is no way to tell the browser to allow wrapping on specific characters.

The CSS3 `word-wrap: break-word;` property will get you part of the way there by allowing the line to break on *any* character. This will happen if the text is longer than the computed maximum width of its containing element.

If you are dynamically generating the HTML output server-side, you could do a regex search and replace to insert a space before the character you'd like to (optionally) wrap on but, without knowing the context, it's hard to be more specific about that.

Answer (score 0):

Just as an alternative, I've used the following in the past:

```
<span style="display:block;float:left;" />
```

or better would be to have this defined in your css:

```
.shy { display:block; float:left; }
```

and then use:

```
<span class="shy" />
```

So where ever you place the above in a string of characters, it will act as a break if need be.

```
stringthathasnospaceswhatsoever<span class="shy" />willbreakjustjustatthespan.
```