# CSS property to specify on which characters a String can be broken

Tags: html, css

If I have a long String (like an URL) Browsers will break it at some characters like `-`, can I specify other characters on which the String should break?

For example:

```
https://www.this-is-my-url.org/upload_dir/2015/01/foo_bar_faq.pdf
```

Having just enough space for 40 characters per line in the box it would break like:

```
                                        | <- this is 40 chars mark
https://www.this-is-my-
url.org/upload_dir/2015/01/foo_bar_faq.pdf
```

and the last line would even cause an overflow, because there is no "breakable char". I'm looking for a CSS-property like:

```
p.url {
  word-break-chars: "_/.";
}
```

So the URL could break on `_`, `/` or `.`and it would look more like:

```
                                        |
https://www.this-is-my-url.org/upload_
dir/2015/01/foo_bar_faq.pdf
```

And `word-break: break-all;` is NOT an option for me! It looks really bad:

```
                                        |
https://www.this-is-my-url.org/upload_di
r/2015/01/foo_bar_faq.pdf
```

Comment: There is no such property.

Comment: Okay, is there an other way? Maybe JS?

Comment: Have you tried to look for a character and split the string at this position? That is a JavaScript solution.

Comment: Maybe this will help you? http://stackoverflow.com/a/13226873/1389366

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Owing to [JavaForAndroid](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2186785/javaforandroid)'s comment I worked out this jQuery solution:

```
$( document ).ready(
    $('.download a').each(function(){
        var newText = $(this).text().replace('_', '_\u200B')
                .replace('/', '/\u200B')
                .replace('.', '.\u200B');

        $(this).text(newText);
    })
);
```

Where `\u200B` is the Unicode for a 'Zero Width Space'.

The HTML looks like:

```
<div class="download">
    <a href="https://www.this-is-my-url.org/upload_dir/2015/01/foo_bar_faq.pdf">
        https://www.this-is-my-url.org/upload_dir/2015/01/foo_bar_faq.pdf
    </a>
    <a href="https://www.this-is-my-url.org/upload_dir/2014/11/foo_bar.pdf">
        https://www.this-is-my-url.org/upload_dir/2014/11/foo_bar.pdf
    </a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use `text-overflow: clip;`

```css
p{
    white-space: nowrap; 
    width: 12em; 
    overflow-x: auto;
    text-overflow: clip; 
    border: 1px solid #000000;
}
```

```html
<p title="https://www.this-is-my-
url.org/upload_dir/2015/01/foo_bar_faq.pdf">https://www.this-is-my-
url.org/upload_dir/2015/01/foo_bar_faq.pdf</p>
```

Comment: I think I will do it like @JavaForAndroid suggested it with JS